# Loop through array values?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

So I have a listbox of salaries. And a button, which if clicked, shows the number of salaries above the average salary amount, and the number below the average salary amount. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to form this loop which return the number below and above the avg. salary amount. Here is what I have so far:

```
    double[] employeeSalary = new double[7] { 8500.50, 7005.99, 9123.00, 100123.50, 6550.00, 8123.90, 7500.95 };
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = employeeSalary;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double avgSalary;
        avgSalary = employeeSalary.Average();
        for (int i = 0; i < employeeSalary.Length; i++)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "return the number below and above"?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. what exactly do you want to return? and where to?

Comment: I mean the button should result in a message box which tells the user how many of the listed salaries are above the average salary amount, and how many of the listed salaries are below the avg. salary amount.

Answer (score 4):

You already used LinQ, you can use it for the other tasks, too:

```
var avgSalary = employeeSalary.Average();
var aboveAverageCount = employeeSalary.Count(x => x > avgSalary);
var belowAverageCount = employeeSalary.Count(x => x < avgSalary);
```